# Angular: HttpClient read full response with Observable Array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service which returns an Observable array of `Movie` type objects:

```
getPage(num: number, limit: number): Observable<Array<Movie>>{
  const url: string = `${environment.apiUrl}/movies?_page=${num}&_limit=${limit}`;
  return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>(url);
}
```

The component looks like this:

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = this.movieService.getPage(2, 10);
...
```

and the template:

```
<div movieItem *ngFor="let movie of movies$ | async">
...
```

This code works as expected.

---

Now, I need to get the full response from `HttpClient` but I'm running into a problem trying to get the `Observable<Movie[]>` object I need to use in the template.

Using [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response), I've modified the service code as follows:

```
getPage(num: number, limit: number): Observable<HttpResponse<Movie[]>>{
  const url: string = `${environment.apiUrl}/movies?_page=${num}&_limit=${limit}`;
  return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>(url,{ observe: 'response' })
}
```

and then in the component, I'm doing this:

```
movies$: Observable<Movie[]>;

getPage() {
  this.movieService.getPage(2, 10)
    .subscribe(resp => {
    const keys = resp.headers.keys();
    this.movies$ = of({ ... resp.body });
  });
}
```

which produces no output from the `*ngFor`. The `resp.body` contains an array as expected but I can't figure out how to get the `Observable<Movie[]>` from it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this block is ok:

```
getPage(num: number, limit: number): Observable<Array<Movie>> {
const url: string = `${environment.apiUrl}/movies?_page=${num}&_limit=${limit}`;
return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>(url);
}
```

Then in the ngOnInit():

```
this.movies$: this.movieService.getPage(2, 10);
```

And that's it.

Comment: No, that's what I already have - it works but doesn't get me the full response from HttpClient. I need to get at the response headers too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, answering my own question...

I got it to work but my solution feels clunky.

Given that the return type from the service has changed, I modified the corresponding type in the component:

```
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  movies$: Observable<HttpResponse<Movie[]>>
...
```

and directly assigned the result of the service call:

```
this.movies$ = this.movieService.getPage(2, 10);
```

Finally, in the template, I added `?.body` to point `*ngFor` at the iterable contained in the response body:

```
<div movieItem *ngFor="let movie of (movies$ | async)?.body">
```

So now I can iterate over the data and also access the HTTP response headers.

It works but I can't help feeling there has to be a better way of doing it.

Suggestions would be welcome.