# how to get response headers?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 15.0. I get a list of items from backend (asp.net core 5) with an item appended to the header. the get method in the client side service is:

```js
/** GET Paged commodities from the server ===============================*/
  getPagedCommodities(pageSize: number, pageNumber: number): Observable<CommodityForList[]> {
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('pageSize', pageSize);
    params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      observe: 'response'
    });

    return this.http.get<CommodityForList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getPagedCommodities/', { headers, params });

  }
```

this method sends two parameters to the server and gets commodities list along with `totalCount` to paging the list. I need the `totalCount` to set the `length` property of `mat-paginator` and commodities list as **observable** to provide a dynamic search for user. therefore, in the `commoditiesList` component, the snippet code for this purpose is:

```js
 commoditiesForList$!: Observable<CommodityForList[]>;
 
this.commoditiesForList$ = this.commoditiesService.getPagedCommodities(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex+1);
 
this.commoditiesForList$.subscribe( res => {
      const totalCount = res.headers.get('X-Pagination');
    })
```

but, here I have an error: `Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'CommodityForList[]'.`
when I change the type of `commoditiesForList$` to `HttpResponse<CommodityForList[]>`, the error may be fixed, but receiving the commodities list as observable will have a problem. Is there a solution to get the commodities list as **observable** and read the `totalCount` separately from the header? thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

See https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

> You might need more information about the transaction than is contained in the response body. Sometimes servers return special headers or status codes to indicate certain conditions that are important to the application workflow.

```js
  getPagedCommodities(pageSize: number, pageNumber: number): Observable<HttpResponse<CommodityForList[]>> {
    // ...
    return this.http.get<CommodityForList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getPagedCommodities/', { headers, params });
  }
```

You can access the body in the `body` attribute.

See maybe also [Angular: HttpClient read full response with Observable Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64344748/9816335).

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you could use the next configuration on your HTTP request: `{responseType: 'json', observe: 'events' }`. See a working example here on [stackblitz - one request](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rc9rsv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
commoditiesForList$!: BehaviourSubject<CommodityForList[]>;
totalCount$!: BehaviourSubject<any>;

constructor(commoditiesService: CommoditiesService) {
this.commoditiesService.getPagedCommodities(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex+1).subscribe(res => {
  this.commoditiesForList$.next(res.body)
  this.totalCount$.next(headers.get('X-Pagination'))
})
}
```

### Original Answer

Given your example, you could use the next configuration on your HTTP request: `{responseType: 'json', observe: 'events' }`. See a working example here on [stackblitz - two requests - shared pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fyyg9v?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Edit: to avoid making two request, notice that GET request is using share operator from rxjs. Thanks Arber to notice it.

```js
getPagedCommodities(pageSize: number, pageNumber: number): Observable<CommodityForList[]> {
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('pageSize', pageSize);
    params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      observe: 'response'
    });

    return this.http.get<CommodityForList[]>(this.baseUrl + '/getPagedCommodities/',
    { headers, params, responseType: 'json',observe: 'events'}).pipe(share());

  }
```

then you will access data and headers in this way

```js
 commoditiesForList$!: Observable<CommodityForList[]>;
 
this.commoditiesForList$ = this.commoditiesService.getPagedCommodities(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex+1).pipe(
    map((res) => (res as any).body));

this.totalCount$ =  this.commoditiesService.getPagedCommodities(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex+1).pipe(
    map((res) => (res as any).headers)), map(headers => headers.get('X-Pagination')));
```

**Docs**: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server

Comment: That way you will send two requests in order to read different data from the responses which you could get both from just one response.

Comment: You are right! I will add "share pipe" and it will fix that problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to the solution you suggested, two requests must be made to the server to get the response body and header? Is it possible to get both with one request?

Comment: Yes, sure we can do it, using share pipe and using just one request. I will edit my answer